# Matching output based on two different array indexes

Tags: php

I have a situation where results in one db table (t1) are stored with the dates of the week corresponding to this array:

```
$xweek = array(1 => "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
```

However, I need to output data from another (t2) table where days of the week are based on this array:

```
$yweek = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
```

As you can see the indexes do not match. How do I sync this? Do I need to create another array that can be used in t1?

```
$zweek = array(6 => 1, 0 => 2, 1 => 3, 2 => 4, 3 => 5, 4 => 6, 5 => 7);

foreach ($yweek AS $k => $v) {

    $t1_Data[$k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a combination of [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)/[array_unshift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php) and [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
$xweek = array(1 => "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",     "Friday", "Saturday");
$yweek = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",          "Saturday", "Sunday");
```

If you want to transform `$xweek` to match the format of `$yweek`:
    array_push($xweek, array_shift($xweek));

```
var_dump($xweek);
```

If you want to transform `$yweek` to match the format of `$xweek`:
    array_push($yweek, array_shift($yweek));

```
var_dump($yweek);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function that translates the american day of week order to the european:

```
function getEuroDow($d){
    return $d==0 ? 6 : $d-1;
}
```

then use it like:

```
foreach($t1_Data AS $k => $v) {
    $t1_Data[getEuroDow($k)];
}
```

This way you wont have to alter the array.